# mysql jdbc batch inserts and updates into different tables

Tags: mysql, jdbc, batch-processing

I need to insert millions of records into mysql database. 
I want to use the batch execute option.
But my SQL statements are for different tables and they should execute in the same sequence.

```
Table 1 insert 1 record
Table 2 insert 1 record using the Table 1's id (key)
Table 3 insert 20 records using the Table 2's id
Table 1 insert 1 record
Table 2 insert 1 record using the Table 1's second record's id
Table 3 insert 20 records using the Table 2's second record's id
```

right now i am executing one statement at a time. How to change this into batch execution to save time.

Thanking you
Aadil

Comment: You can't use batch inserts for this, except maybe for the 20 inserts into table 3.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I am thinking about doing this way.

statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.addBatch("insert the record in table 1");
statement.addBatch("insert the record in table 2. Get the max(id) from table 1");
statement.addBatch("insert records in table 3. Get the max(id) from table 2");
statement.executeBatch();

May be not a good option but i will continue to think for the best solution.